# Function isn't formatting numbers correctly

Tags: php, function

I made a contact form for gathering information from viewers, it's working correctly except for the phone number format, whatever gets entered seems to just come out with no formatting. I'm not sure what's wrong.

For example if I enter 123 555 7890 into the form, it comes back as "1235557890" instead as (123) 555-7890.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "my_email";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $name = stripcslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = stripcslashes($_POST['email']);
    $tel = stripcslashes($_POST['tel']);
    $message = stripcslashes($_POST['message']);

    function formatTelNumaber($tel) {
        $tel = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $tel);

        if (strlen($tel) > 10) {
            $countryCode = substr($tel, 0, strlen($tel) - 10);
            $areaCode = substr($tel, -10, 3);
            $prefix = substr($tel, -7, 3);
            $lineNumber = substr($tel, -4, 4);

            $tel = '+' . $countryCode . '(' . $areaCode . ') ' . $prefix . '-' . $lineNumber;
            echo $tel;
        } elseif (strlen($tel == 10)) {
            $areaCode = substr($tel, 0, 3);
            $prefix = substr($tel, 3, 3);
            $lineNumber = substr($tel, 6, 4);

            $tel = '(' . $areaCode . ') ' . $prefix . '-' . $lineNumber;
            echo $tel;
        } elseif (stat($tel) == 7) {
            $prefix = substr($tel, 0, 3);
            $lineNumber = substr($tel, 3, 4);

            $tel = $prefix . '-' . $lineNumber;
            echo $tel;
        }

        return $tel;
    }

    $msgBody = 'Name: ' . $name . "<br>" . 'Email:' . $email . "<br>" . 'Phone Number: ' . formatTelNumaber($tel) . "<br>" . 'Message: ' . "<br>" . $message;
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email;

    if (mail($to, $subject, $msgBody, $headers)) {
        $msg = "Message Sent Successfully!";
    } else {
        $msg = "Message Not Sent! Please Try Again";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="me">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <title>Contact Form</title>

        <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body class="bg-info">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-4 bg-light rounded mt-3">
                    <h4 class="text-center text-dark p-2">Contact Form</h4>
                    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="p-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email</label><br>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@email.com" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Phone Number</label><br>
                            <input type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="(123) 555-8888" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message</label><br>
                            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message..." required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 class="text-center text-success"><?= $msg; ?></h4>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you generally shouldn't put function definitions inside `if` blocks.

Comment: `strlen($tel == 10)` won't do what you want, therefore it's not hitting that `else if` block

Comment: *it comes back as* Do you mean from the database ? If so check the field type you have for the phone maybe it only support numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
       } elseif (strlen($tel == 10)) {
```

The `== 10` should be outside the function call:

```
       } elseif (strlen($tel) == 10) {
```

And

```
        } elseif (stat($tel) == 7) {
```

should call `strlen()`, not `stat()`; `stat()` requires `$tel` to be a filename, it returns an array of information about the file.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Man you have no idea how long I was looking over this and must have missed that problem. Thank you! I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: I just changed the answer. It looks like removing the non-digit characters is necessary so that the length checks will work.

Comment: But the errors in the length checks caused the formatting code to go wrong.